# How to set height on <ion-img>

Tags: html, css, image, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an ionic page with an **ion-img** inside:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="ion-padding" align-items-center justify-content-center>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label text-wrap class="ion-text-center">
          Servicio de reportes
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row align-items-center justify-content-center >
      <ion-button size="smaill" type="submit" expand="block" routerDirection="forward" (click)="selectSource()" >Capturar imagen</ion-button>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>

        <ion-img [src]="selectedImage" *ngIf="selectedImage"> </ion-img>

      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

When a picture is set to **selectedImage** it occupies the whole screen and more. I have to scrrol to see the full image.

I want the image to occupy 20% of the screen or a fix height.

I tried to do this in css:

```
ion-grid {
  height: 100%;

  ion-row {
    max-height: 33.33%;
  }
}
```

And also I tried to do with height property:

```
 <ion-img height: 10rem; [src]="selectedImage" *ngIf="selectedImage"> </ion-img>
```

And the image continues occupying the same space

How should I do this? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if u Reduce image height write  inline style< img src="" style="width:50%" >use this attribute image size(height) will reduce automatically

No option to maximize  image size

Comment: I tried this:         <ion-row align-items-center justify-content-center>
            <ion-col align-self-center [size]="12" *ngIf="selectedImage != '' && selectedImage != undefined && selectedImage != null">
                <ion-img  style="width:50%" [src]=" selectedImage"></ion-img>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row> But this places the image on the right side of the screen, how can I solve this new problem?

Comment: use margin attribute for image tag
ex:<ion-row >
          <ion-col  size="12"
            *ngIf="selectedImage != '' && selectedImage != undefined && selectedImage != null">
            <img style="width:50%" class="img" [src]=" selectedImage">
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
<--css-->
.img{
margin:50%;
}

may be this code will help

Answer (score 8):

I know that the accepted answer does the requested results, but using the ionic `ion-img` tag have advantages like ***lazy loading*** and listening to the loading events (`ionError, ionImgDidLoad, ionImgWillLoad`).

I don't prefer to lose all that tag advantages in favor of styling.
The better way to do this is using the [CSS shadow parts](https://ionicframework.com/blog/customize-your-ionic-framework-app-with-css-shadow-parts/).

[ion-img has a shadow part `image`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/img#css-shadow-parts) so the requested result via SCSS will look like:

```css
ion-img::part(image) {
  width: 50%; /* or whatever value */
  /* you can set the height value too */
}
```